# overriding magento search

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a Magento website configured with 1 website and 2 stores. Each store products are separated with root category, means each store has their own root category.

I want the products from store A not searchable from store B.
How to override search to do such thing? which method should I look into?

Note: I don't want to use Visibility setting due to some reasons such as it will make a product from another store not clickable in cart/mini cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put addAttributeToFilter by rewriting `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer::getProductCollection()`

`app/code/local/Vela/CatalogSearch/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Vela_CatalogSearch>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vela_CatalogSearch>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <models>
        <catalogsearch>
        <rewrite>
            <layer>Vela_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer</layer>
        </rewrite>
        </catalogsearch>
    </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then in my `app/code/local/Vela/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php` file

```
<?php

class Vela_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Layer
{
public function getProductCollection()
{
  if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
      $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
  } else {
      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection');
      $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
      $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
  }

  // start modification
  $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
  $store_code =  Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();

  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
  $_attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('universo_store');
  if ($_attr->usesSource()) {
      $_attr_option_id_seafolly = $_attr->getSource()->getOptionId("seafolly");
      $_attr_option_id_havaianas = $_attr->getSource()->getOptionId("seafolly");
  }

  if(stripos('seafolly',$store_code) !== FALSE){ // seafolly
      $store_id = $_attr_option_id_seafolly;
  } else {//havaianas
      $store_id = $_attr_option_id_havaianas;
  }

  $collection->addAttributeToFilter('universo_store', array('eq'=>$store_id));
  // end modification

  return $collection;
}
}
```

Comment: i will, i am waiting for the timer to go off

Answer (score 2):

unassign products of Store A that you don't want to be shown in Store B, and they won't be searchable. ( Websites Tab in Product Edit mode)

Comment: how to "unassign" them in particural store?
i have products assigned to root category for store B searchable from store A that has another root category.

Comment: in backend Catalog->Manage Products-> Edit a product  Websites Tab, uncheck the site you don't want that product to appear in.

Comment: it's multi store, not multi website. Multi website will make it harder to manage the session (login, cart, etc) between websites. and our site shares the cart and login session between stores.

Answer (score 1):

To override the search you should rewrite the ResultController from catalogsearch module in magento core.
It would be nice to override helper also.

Comment: already looked into it and i need to put addAttributeToFilter on the collection. where should i put it?